# Differential equation, first order but not first degree.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$.
$$3p^2y^2-2xyp+4y^2-x^2=0 \\ p=\frac{2xy\pm\sqrt{4x^2y^2-4(3y^2)(4y^2-x^2)}}{6y^2} \\ 
p=\frac{2xy\pm2\sqrt{x^2y^2-(12y^4-3x^2y^2)}}{6y^2} \\ 
p=\frac{x\pm2\sqrt{x^2-3y^2}}{3y}$$

I am not able to proceed from here. What I have is the following. 
$$\frac{3ydy-xdx}{\sqrt{x^2-3y^2}}=\pm2ydx$$

For reference answer given in the book is

> $$2x\pm(x^2-3y^2)^{1/2}=c$$

Comment: I think you should get $dx$ and $dy$ to diffrent sides.

Comment: yes but i am not able to separate the variables as you can see. Other method would be to find an integrating factor\

Comment: ${3ydy}=(\pm {\sqrt{x^2-3y^2}}\times 2y+x)dx$

Comment: This might not be of any help, but the left hand side equals $d(-\sqrt{x^2-3y^2})$.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I made a mistake. I got it now. 
$$3y\frac{dy}{dx}-x=\pm\sqrt{x^2-3y^2} \\ \frac{3ydy-xdx}{\sqrt{x^2-3y^2}}=\pm dx \\ -\frac{1}{2}d(\sqrt{x^2-3y^2})=\pm dx \\ 2x\pm\sqrt{x^2-3y^2}=c$$